# Why does my system clock differ across services?

Tags: linux, time

I have my system clock set to UK time, which is currently +0100 (BST)
I set this by symlinking the localtime file, as follows

```
/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London
```

- The date command correctly shows the
  time as +0100.
- File modification
  timestamps also treat the time as
  +0100.

However:

- MySQL still thinks it's -0400.
- Cron also thinks it's -0400.

I run a few very similar servers, (CentOS 5 on a VPS) and have not had this problem before.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Restarting MySQL fixed that one.

Restarting Cron did not

Answer (score 0):

You may have wrong locale settings in your environment. See what's the output of `locale`.

Comment: locale gives me this:

    `LANG=
    LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
    LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
    LC_TIME="POSIX"
    LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
    LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
    LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
    LC_PAPER="POSIX"
    LC_NAME="POSIX"
    LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
    LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX" 
    LC_ALL=`

Comment: which is identical to another similar VPS that is working fine

Comment: You definitely don't have the correct locale set then. I'd recommend setting it. As to the difference in time, you may add a line to MySQL script and a job to cron to see the output of locale from inside. If they are set to something other than POSIX, this would explain the difference.

Comment: From a cronjob, I get the same output.

Comment: I managed to fix MySQL by restarting. restarting cron didn't fix though.

Answer (score 0):

Check presence of TZ environment variable. See `man tzset` for description of its format and how time zone info is defined.